# [myArray objectAtIndex:i].property in kvc

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding, kvc

Anybody know the kvc key/key path fore this code

```
[myArray objectAtIndex:i].property
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, the closest you can go is probably:

```
[[myArray valueForKey:@"property"] objectAtIndex:i]
```

because arrays do not implement KVC for themselves, they redefine it to apply the key to the elements and return an array of the results.

Comment: It should be other way.. `[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"property"];`

Comment: I know these methods is there any single keypath for that

Comment: no. there cannot be as KVC with an array cannot access a single content object. It's either an array of results (one for each object), the array size, or an aggregate value on all content objects (like the maximum, minimum, average etc.).